# Retrieve key of a dynamic hash

Tags: perl

How can I retrieve a "key" from a dynamic hash?

Code example:

```
sub HASH($){
    my %hash;
    my $pass = shift;
    open (my $file, '<', "infofile") || die "No such file or dir\n";
    %hash=map split, <$file>;
    return $hash{$pass};
}
```

My infofile looks like this:

```
user   passwd
raid   12345
```

The code returns the password if the user is found. How can I return the username only?

Comment: you are using `$pass` and `$passw`, one is likely a typo.

Comment: Security don't matter here, learning only !.

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. Thnaks :)

Comment: Are you trying to find the user that corresponds to a given password?

Comment: No. Just extract the username from the file

Comment: I'd suggest `... || die $!`.  There are open() errors other than "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add (for debugging purposes) a print of the hash,

```
open (my $file, '<', "infofile") || die "No such file or dir\n";
%hash=map split, <$file>;

for (keys %hash) {
  print "$_: $hash{$_}\n";
}
```

you will see:

```
raid: 12345
user: passwd
```

Therefore I would argue, that your variable `$pass` is actually the username, and a `return $pass;` would return the username. I cannot image this is what you want. On the other hand finding the user that corresponds to a given password doesn't sound very likely either.

Comment: And your argument is 100% correct. My mistake-- Apologies, its working thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
sub HASH($){
 my %hash;
 my $pass = shift;
 open (my $file, '<', "infofile") || die "No such file or dir\n";
 %hash=map split, <$file>;
 my ($user,$selecteduser);
  foreach $user (keys %hash){
   $selecteduser = $user if $hash{$user} eq $pass;
  }
 return $selecteduser;
}
```

Comment: I read the shifted $pass as being the password being passed to the subroutine. Otherwise the OP question is, how do I get the keys of a hash?